# Post P2V Remote Destkop

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, physical-to-virtual

I recently performed a P2V on an old OEM XP installation.

This required running an in place install to convert from an OEM to a VLK. 
On completion I was unable to connect to remote desktop. netstat -ano | find "3389" returns nothing.

I tried axing and the [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server] keys and importing from a known good source. This resulted in the service listening on 3389 but failing with "an error occurred while the connection was being established".

As far as I can tell the only difference between these two sets of registry keys are the color depth, a few printers and a VIDEO subkey:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\VIDEO\disc]
>   "VgaCompatible"="\Device\Video0"
>   "\Device\Video0"="\REGISTRY\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TSDDD\Device0"

I also tried a [frequently referenced KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270588/en-us) and devcon. No change.

```
devcon.exe -r install %windir%\inf\machine.inf root\rdpdr
```

I'm at a loss as to a solution to this issue.

EDIT - I'm sure that the necessary service is running and that the system is set up to allow remote access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a working solution for this issue. In the end there were several points that needed to be addressed.

1: The OEM license key, addressed by an in place repair.

2: Ghost devices. The P2V did not remove all the old hardware references included by the OS. To resolve I used a [third devcon party script](http://www.boche.net/blog/index.php/2011/06/11/scripted-removal-of-non-present-hardware-after-a-p2v/) to remove all the extraneous entries.

3:  A "Terminal Server Device Redirector" device was showing as not having the proper drivers installed. This was the result of the P2V. Resolved by removing the device.

4: Recreate the TS devices with devcon: devcon.exe -r install %windir%\inf\machine.inf root\rdpdr

5: Terminal Services not was still not functioning, not listening at all on port 3389 (via netstat -ano). To resolve I exported the registry keys from another VM with the same OS, SP and patch level and imported into the trouble VM.

Several sites indicated that a specific key \Device\Video0 is all that needs to be set. I found this *not* to be the case in my environment. 
Only after executing these in the exact order listed did I achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the machine is setup for RDP still?  Might just need to disable then enable RDP.  Is the RDP service running?

Comment: Positive - I have group policy in place for those items.